# I want to update the existing logo for my PWA app

Tags: progressive-web-apps

When I am updating the logo of the PWA app the icon is not getting updated for the previously installed applications. 
However for newly installed apps I am getting the correct logo.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try updating the new image icon in manifest.json & then showing a prompt to users to refresh the PWA?

Comment: Not yet will try that

Answer (score 0):

You can try to have a look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/integration/webapks#update-webapk) for Android APK (from the question is not clear your target device: web or mobile).

> Chrome will periodically compare the locally installed manifest against a copy of the manifest fetched from the network. If any of the properties in the manifest required to add the PWA to the home screen have changed in the network copy, Chrome will request an updated WebAPK, reflecting those new values.

This feature is not yet available for desktop, but planned in a  future release.

Do you use any framework (Angular, React) to build your PWA? If you want to read more details about how to install an app on the homescreen or the web manifest properties, you can [have a look here](https://dev.to/paco_ita/install-a-pwa-on-the-user-s-device-step-2-27pa).